# Different gyroscope values in chrome mobile and safari mobile

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, device-orientation

I am currently building a small panoramic photo viewer which has an option to navigate the scene with a gyroscope.  I am taking the data from the deviceOrientation event and turning the euler angles into a rotation matrix, and then putting that through some transformations and eventually moving a css cube with a 3dMatrix transform.

My problem is that I am getting very different data coming in from the deviceOrientation event on different browsers on different devices, and I don't understand why.

On almost every iPhone I have tried, with safari mobile and with Chrome, everything works great.  The values come in and make sense, and the whole experience is quite seamless.

On a Samsung Galaxy S3, in Chrome, my data is totally erratic.  The alpha value doesn't actually seem to represent a rotation around the z axis, and there are huge leaps in values, like the beta leaping from 50-130 degrees with only a small motion.

On a Galaxy Tab S 8.4" in Chrome, i still get some erratic values, with some jerking back and forth, but I at least get something that approximates the desired behaviour.

On a Nexus 7 2nd gen, on Chrome, the experience is coherent and makes sense.  Its rendering is choppy compared to the iPhone but it is rotating everything properly, and the values make sense.

Does anyone know how I might be able to fix these issues, or how I should address them?  They may be a problem with Samsungs port of Android, or in Android itself in the newest versions of the OS.

Thoughts? Ideas? Suggestions?  I am really lost at this point.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here you can find the details of the JS events:
http://dorukeker.com/know-thy-gyroscope-and-js-part-i/

Here is which values are different on which devices:
 http://dorukeker.com/know-thy-gyroscope-and-js-part-ii/

And here is the JS file I prepared to deal with these differences:
 https://github.com/dorukeker/gyronorm.js

UPDATE: I have just updated the gyronorm.js on GitHub. Now there are functions that tells you if a certain variable is available on the device/browser combination. Check the GitHub page to download and how to use.

I hope these help.
Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks so much for this!  I'll try installing it into our app and see how it does.

I have had some very weird behaviour recently, specifically with Samsung devices with their newest OS installed.  The values are just erratic and make no sense.  The alpha sticks at 259deg for like 1/2-3/4 of a turn around the z axis, then flicks down to 180 or so, then down to 90.  No in between values.  It resembled something working before I installed the new OS and then after, garbage data.

Comment: I have just ran a quick test with a Samsung Galaxy S5 with KitKat 4.4.2 In the native browser I see what you mentioned but in Chrome it works as expected. :( I will look into it in more detail and try to come up with a fix. I will let you know if/when it is ready.

Comment: Thanks so much Doruk!  There still seems to be a lot of inconsistency among devices.  Right now, I am still having trouble on all Samsung devices.  

My Samsung s3 is totally screwy.  It does flips and twirls, and behaves totally illogically to the actualy alpha, beta and gamma angles.

A Samsung Tab 10.1 and an Acer Iconia A1-830, in both Firefox and Chrome 37, doesn't give me any data at all from the Gyroscope API.  I just get NULL values.

My code works perfectly on all iPhones I have tested it on, as well as on a Nexus 7.

Comment: Right now, the only solution I can come up with is to sniff the user agent, and only support specific devices which the feature works well with. I also think that this issue has something to do with Samsung's gyroscope code in the newest release of their proprietary build of Android. It may be that Google is aware of this, and has shut down their gyroscope API until the issue is fixed.

Comment: - In iPhone we trust :) luckily it works as expected almost always. - Samsung S3 is rather old device/os not sure they implemented the standard as expected. - The alpha, beta and gamma angles are Euler angles and they work slightly different then rotations around axises. To get the rotation around axises you need to apply them in a certain order or apply as Euler angles if it is supported in your target platform (such as Unity3D). In the part-I of the blog posts there is an example from Mozilla.

Comment: I am planning to add some "isSupported" properties to GyroNorm so you do not need to spoof the device. I also will update the demo file so you can test the devices more easily. But again I cannot promise when. For now make sure you have nice fall backs :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found (in past when working with device orientation, not sure if this has changed) that one of the axis values on android are inverted from the iOS values. I had to create a wrapper method for deviceorientation that would invert android and apply some obscure multiplier to get the values to be comparable, but the sensitivity between android phones will vary so you will have to settle for finding some acceptable middle ground.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try comparing values side by side and see if I can get it to make more sense.  I'll report back if I have any findings.